# Drawing a partial sprite with batch-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, sprite

I have a sprite like this.

[image]

I want to draw this sprite in such a way that sprite is growing from bottom to top, using sprite batch on tap.for that,I have written the following code:

```
  if (MyInputProcessor.isTap)
{
Sprite stickSprite = new Sprite(stickTexture);
stickSprite.setPosition(stick.getX(),stick.getY());
for(float n=0;n<100;n++)
{
     float i = 0.01f * n;
    batch.draw(
    stickSprite.getTexture(),
     stick.getX(),         
     stick.getY(),    
         stickSprite.getWidth() / 2,
         stickSprite.getHeight() / 2,            

         stickSprite.getWidth(),                                                   
         stickSprite.getHeight()*i,  //multiplying with height                                            
         stickSprite.getScaleX(),       
         stickSprite.getScaleY(),       
        0 ,                                    
        stickSprite.getRegionX(),      
        stickSprite.getRegionY(),      

        stickSprite.getRegionWidth(),
        stickSprite.getRegionHeight(), 
        false,
        false); 


 }
MyInputProcessor.isTap = false;
```

}

Here the i value increments but not taking effect in the code to scale.
Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called this method in render before drawing the sprite.

```
stickSprite.setSize(stickSprite.getWidth(), stickSprite.getHeight() + addincrementvalue);
```